# How many T/F answer keys are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A professor writes 40 discrete mathematics true/false questions. Of the statements in these questions, 17 are true. If the order matters here , how many different answer keys are possible?

---

I know that if order does not matters, then it is simply a combination problem of choosing 17 out of 40 elements.

But now order matters here, So I answered it as C(40,17) * 2^40.

Am I right here ?

Comment: Where does the $2^{40}$ come in?  It's just a matter of picking the true $17$.

Comment: Once you choose $17$ out of $40$ questions to be true, and the remaining $23$ are false. And now there is nothing more to do, the answer key is determined. So the answer is $C(40,17)$; the factor of $2^{40}$ is wrong.

Comment: @LeeMosher, Order matters here !! Won't it effect ?

Comment: @Willturner: Exactly what does "order matters" mean in this context?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, That where I am going wrong .

Comment: @Willturner: I'm sorry, that response does not clarify for me what it is you mean.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, What i think that there is no order here . This question resembles bit strings . So, it is just selecting 17 out of 40 .Am i right now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is same as bit string question in which Total length of bit string is 40. Of which 17 are 1's and 23 are 0's.

So, by using permutations, we are having total 40 elements in which 17 are of one kind and 23 are of other kind.

**So, the whole problem reduces to 40! / (17! * 23!) = C(40,17)**

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that $C(40,17)$ for true answers since their order does not matter as long as he/she got it right and then I multiplied them by $C(40,23)$ for false questions, so it would be $C(40,17) \times C(40,23)$ since I did not see or understand from the answer that it's meant correct answers. Please correct me if I am wrong.